# 2014 VW Passat AC vents randomly moves from front to floor vents

Tags: vw, ac, passat, vents

While driving and using the AC on the Main front vent setting, it will randomly blow down on my feet. Sometimes it's a little of both and sometimes it will go back on its own.

The get it working again, I move it to the defrost position, wait for it to blow 100% through them and then I change back to the front vents. This happens often and is frustrating when it's really hot out or when I have flip flops on.

I've seen a post suggesting it could be a vacuum line, but that was a Ford Explorer. Does anyone have any different advice or some documentation to help troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!